# CM 12.1 random restarts

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-xperia-z2

I've got Cyanogenmod 12.1 and it randomly restarts. It seems to only do this when I'm using the phone, for example I've never had it restart when the phone was just sitting unused. Is there anyway I can prevent this or find what's causing it?

Comment: who's responsible for -1?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having a nightly build and there is no way you could fix it manually. All you can do is report bugs or hope that a stable build comes around.

Comment: There are only nightly builds for CM 12 so I guess there's nothing that can be done. Would it be any more stable if I used an older nightly build?